# Using a variable to calculate the tax on an invoice

Tags: calculations, invoice

I've customized a class to obtain the tax value and also the total amount in an invoice. This is the portion I need to modify:

```
{
\hline\hline\hline
{Valor venta} & & & {S/. \total{cost}} \\
{IGV (\taxval \%)} & & & {S/. \taxes{\money}{\taxval}} \\
{Importe total} & & & {S/. \addtaxes{\money}{\taxval}} \\
\end{longtable}
}
\def\money{600}
```

As you can see, "money" is hard-coded. I've tried to replace "\money" with \total{cost} but I usually get an error.

Any idea how to change this?

Here's my document:

```
\documentclass{invoice-spanish} % Use the custom invoice class (invoice.cls)
\def \tab {\hspace*{3ex}} % Define \tab to create some horizontal white space

\usepackage[ngerman,english,spanish]{babel} 
\decimalpoint
\usepackage[latin1,utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}    
\usepackage{hyperref} 
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{datetime}
\usepackage{pgf,pgfmath}
 \usepackage{pgfplots}

%Taxes
\pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu}
\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd,
fixed,
fixed zerofill,
precision=2,
set thousands separator={,},
set decimal separator={.}
}
\newcommand{\taxes}[2]{%
\pgfmathparse{#1*#2/100}%
\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}%
}
\newcommand{\addtaxes}[2]{%
\pgfmathparse{#1+#1*#2/100}%
\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}%
}
\def\taxval{18}

\begin{document}
\begin{invoiceTable}
\feetype{Mantenimiento website y soporte de sistemas} % Fee category description
\hourrow{Configuración de cuentas de correo}{10}{60}
\end{invoiceTable}

\end{document}
```

The full class is here:

```
\ProvidesClass{invoice}

\LoadClass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[letterpaper,hmargin=0.79in,vmargin=0.79in]{geometry}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip} % Do not indent paragraphs
\usepackage{fp} % Fixed-point arithmetic
\usepackage{calc} % Counters for totaling hours and cost
\usepackage{longtable}

\pagestyle{empty} % No page numbers
\linespread{1.5} % Line spacing

\setlength{\doublerulesep}{\arrayrulewidth} % Double rules look like one thick one

% Command for setting a default hourly rate
\newcommand{\feetype}[1]{
\textbf{#1}
\\
}

% Counters for totaling up hours and dollars
\newcounter{hours} \newcounter{subhours} \newcounter{cost} \newcounter{subcost}
\setcounter{hours}{0} \setcounter{subhours}{0}
\setcounter{cost}{0} \setcounter{subcost}{0}

% Formats inputed number with 2 digits after the decimal place
\newcommand*{\formatNumber}[1]{\FPround{\cost}{#1}{2}\cost} %

% Returns the total of counter
\newcommand*{\total}[1]{\FPdiv{\t}{\arabic{#1}}{1000}\formatNumber{\t}}

% Create an invoice table
\newenvironment{invoiceTable}{
% Create a new row from title, unit quantity, unit rate, and unit name
\newcommand*{\unitrow}[4]{%
     \addtocounter{cost}{1000 * \real{##2} * \real{##3}}%
     \addtocounter{subcost}{1000 * \real{##2} * \real{##3}}%
     ##1 & \formatNumber{##2} ##4 & S/. \formatNumber{##3} & S/. \FPmul{\cost}{##2}{##3}\formatNumber{\cost}%
     \\
}
% Create a new row from title and expense amount
\newcommand*{\feerow}[2]{%
     \addtocounter{cost}{1000 * \real{##2}}%
     \addtocounter{subcost}{1000 * \real{##2}}%
     ##1 & & S/. \formatNumber{##2} & S/. \FPmul{\cost}{##2}{1} \formatNumber{\cost}%
     \\
}

\newcommand{\subtotalNoStar}{
    {\bf Subtotal} & {\bf \total{subhours} hours} &  & {\bf S/.  \total{subcost}}
    \setcounter{subcost}{0}
    \setcounter{subhours}{0}
    \\*[1.5ex]
}
\newcommand{\subtotalStar}{
    {\bf Subtotal} & & & {\bf S/.  \total{subcost}}
    \setcounter{subcost}{0}
    \\*[1.5ex]
}
\newcommand{\subtotal}{
     \hline
     \@ifstar
     \subtotalStar%
     \subtotalNoStar%
}

% Create a new row from date and hours worked (use stored fee type and hourly rate)
\newcommand*{\hourrow}[3]{%
    \addtocounter{hours}{1000 * \real{##2}}%
    \addtocounter{subhours}{1000 * \real{##2}}%
    \unitrow{##1}{##2}{##3}{horas}%
}
\renewcommand{\tabcolsep}{0.8ex}
\setlength\LTleft{0pt}
\setlength\LTright{0pt}
\begin{longtable}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}\hspace{\tabcolsep}} l r r r }
\hline
{\bf Detalle de servicio} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\bf Horas} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\bf Costo} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\bf Total} \\*
\hline\hline
\endhead
}{
\hline\hline\hline
{Valor venta} & & & {S/. \total{cost}} \\
{IGV (\taxval \%)} & & & {S/. \taxes{\money}{\taxval}} \\
{Importe total} & & & {S/. \addtaxes{\money}{\taxval}} \\
\end{longtable}
}
\def\money{600}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `\total{cost}` does not mean anything to the `\taxes` and `\addtaxes` commands, which is why they give the error. If, instead, you use `\taxes{\arabic{cost}}` then everything is fine. That is, if you pass them numbers, rather than a macro, it works -- although the formatting is not quite as you would like it.

Having said this, your class file needs a little refactoring. Here are three things that I would change:

- You have a large number of `\newcommand`s sitting inside the definition of the `invoiceTable` environment, which strikes me as being bad practice.
- Your class file uses the commands `\taxval`, `\taxes` and `\addtaxes` all of which are defined in the main tex file.
- The main tex file uses [pgfmath](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf) for calculation whereas the class file uses [fp](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/fp). For consistency you should use one or the other rather than mix and match.

I would replace all of the `fp` commands with `pgfmath` commands myself, but this is probably just because I like `pgfmath` (although `fp` does not seem to be supported anymore, not having changed since 1999)

Below is a small step towards addressing some of the comments above. Probably most importantly it produces the output that you want:

[image]

Here is how I have rewritten your main file:

```
\documentclass{invoice-spanish} % Use the custom invoice class (invoice.cls)
\def \tab {\hspace*{3ex}} % Define \tab to create some horizontal white space

\usepackage[ngerman,english,spanish]{babel}
\decimalpoint
\usepackage[latin1,utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{microtype}
%\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
%\usepackage{hyperref}
%\usepackage{eurosym}
%\usepackage{datetime}
%\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{invoiceTable}
\feetype{Mantenimiento website y soporte de sistemas} % Fee category description
\typeout{starting}
\hourrow{Configuración de cuentas de correo}{10}{60}
\end{invoiceTable}

\end{document}
```

I have commented out some of the packages as they are not needed for the MWE. Adding them back in may require some care as there seem to be conflicts.

Finally, here is the modified class file:

```
\ProvidesClass{invoice}% Should be invoice-spanish??

\LoadClass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[letterpaper,hmargin=0.79in,vmargin=0.79in]{geometry}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip} % Do not indent paragraphs
\usepackage{fp} % Fixed-point arithmetic
\usepackage{pgf,pgfmath}
\usepgflibrary{fpu}
\usepackage{calc} % Counters for totaling hours and cost
\usepackage{longtable}

\pagestyle{empty} % No page numbers
\linespread{1.5} % Line spacing

\setlength{\doublerulesep}{\arrayrulewidth} % Double rules look like one thick one

% Command for setting a default hourly rate -- Q Why not just use \textbf?
\newcommand{\feetype}[1]{\textbf{#1}\\}

%Taxes
\pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=true}
\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd,
  fixed,
  fixed zerofill,
  precision=2,
  set thousands separator={,},
  set decimal separator={.}
}
\newcommand{\taxes}[2]{%
  \pgfmathparse{#1*#2/100000}%
  \pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}%
}
\newcommand{\addtaxes}[2]{%
  \pgfmathparse{#1/1000+#1*#2/100000}%
  \pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}%
}
\def\taxval{18}

% Counters for totaling up hours and dollars
\newcounter{hours}
\newcounter{subhours}
\newcounter{cost}
\newcounter{subcost}

% Formats inputed number with 2 digits after the decimal place
\newcommand*{\formatNumber}[1]{\FPround{\cost}{#1}{2}\cost} %

% Returns the total of counter
\newcommand*{\total}[1]{\pgfmathparse{\arabic{#1}/1000}\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}}

% Create a new row from title, unit quantity, unit rate, and unit name
\newcommand*{\unitrow}[4]{%
     \addtocounter{cost}{1000 * \real{#2} * \real{#3}}%
     \addtocounter{subcost}{1000 * \real{#2} * \real{#3}}%
     #1 & \formatNumber{#2} #4 & S/. \formatNumber{#3} & S/. \FPmul{\cost}{#2}{#3}\formatNumber{\cost}%
     \\
}
% Create a new row from title and expense amount
\newcommand*{\feerow}[2]{%
     \addtocounter{cost}{1000 * \real{#2}}%
     \addtocounter{subcost}{1000 * \real{#2}}%
     #1 & & S/. \formatNumber{#2} & S/. \FPmul{\cost}{#2}{1} \formatNumber{\cost}%
     \\
}

\newcommand{\subtotalNoStar}{
    {\bf Subtotal} & {\bf \total{subhours} hours} &  & {\bf S/.  \total{subcost}}
    \setcounter{subcost}{0}
    \setcounter{subhours}{0}
    \\*[1.5ex]
}
\newcommand{\subtotalStar}{
    {\bf Subtotal} & & & {\bf S/.  \total{subcost}}
    \setcounter{subcost}{0}
    \\*[1.5ex]
}
\newcommand{\subtotal}{
     \hline
     \@ifstar
     \subtotalStar%
     \subtotalNoStar%
}

% Create a new row from date and hours worked (use stored fee type and hourly rate)
\newcommand*{\hourrow}[3]{%
    \addtocounter{hours}{1000 * \real{#2}}%
    \addtocounter{subhours}{1000 * \real{#2}}%
    \unitrow{#1}{#2}{#3}{horas}%
}
\renewcommand{\tabcolsep}{0.8ex}
\setlength\LTleft{0pt}
\setlength\LTright{0pt}
% Create an invoice table
\newenvironment{invoiceTable}{%
  \setcounter{hours}{0} \setcounter{subhours}{0}
  \setcounter{cost}{0} \setcounter{subcost}{0}
  \longtable{@{\extracolsep{\fill}\hspace{\tabcolsep}} l r r r }
  \hline
  {\bf Detalle de servicio} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\bf Horas} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\bf Costo} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\bf Total} \\*
  \hline\hline
  \endhead
  }{
  \hline\hline\hline
  {Valor venta} & & & {S/. \total{cost}} \\
  {IGV (\taxval \%)} & & & {S/. \taxes{\arabic{cost}}{\taxval}} \\
  {Importe total} & & & {S/. \addtaxes{\arabic{cost}}{\taxval}} \\
  \endlongtable
  }
```

I have not fixed everything and there are a few questions in the comments. Currently the file does what you want (btw you seem to multiply by `1000` in a few places which means that you have to divide by it in others...this should also be simplified).

Comment: Thanks for the thorough explanation. Inasmuch as I'm no expert in LaTeX, my example was created using pieces from other files, hence the chaotic inclusion of packages and stuff that isn't used by the file. But I'm learning, for sure. Well, everything's working fine now, I'm really happy with the results! Thanks again.